# Read arguments from constructor call

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, arguments

Given

```
const anInstance = new Plugin({ a: 'path' })
```

Can you return the arguments given?

```
anInstance./* some method */ === [{ a: 'path' }]

// or

someWrapper(anInstance) === [{ a: 'path' }]
```

Restrictions:

1. You cannot change the internal implementation of `Plugin`: treat as an external dependency.
2. `Plugin` may have more than one argument, of any type.
3. You cannot assign the initial arguments to an external variable, like so:

   ```
   const config = { a: 'path' }
   const anInstance = new Plugin(config)
   ```

---

**Background**: I'm trying to write a test for a webpack plugin configuration. For example:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new wepback.DllPlugin({
      name: '[name]',
      path: path.join(buildDir, '[name].json'),
    })
  ]
}
```

I want to test the configuration given to the DllPlugin. Restriction #3 above is there because I don't want to have to export the config for each plugin when the only consumer of that export would be my test.

If there's no way to do my initial ask, then I'll have to add those exports, as I can't think of any other way to access those arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `class`, use `extend`

```js
function Plugin() {}

class getPluginArgs extends Plugin {
  constructor(...args) {
    super();
    this.args = args;
    for (let arg of args) {
      console.log(arg)
    }
  }
  getArgs() {
    return this.args;
  }
}

const anInstance = new getPluginArgs({ a: "path" });
console.log(anInstance instanceof Plugin, anInstance.getArgs());
```

Comment: Would I have to do this for each class? For instance, if I had `Plugin` and `Plugin2`, I'd need `getPluginArgs` and `getPluginArgs2`?

Comment: @neezer If the functions are different, yes. `Plugin` is different than `Plugin2`, yes? You could probably create a function  which you can pass the function reference to, which creates and extends the `class`, to perform the process.

Comment: @neezer See also [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Yeah, `Plugin, Plugin2, ... PluginN` are all different and distinct, so I'd love a solution that isn't tied to any specific version.

Comment: @neezer Note, the original Question does not describe performing the process on multiple constructors. The requirement at original Question  describes getting arguments passed to `Plugin`. If the requirement is to get the arguments passed to the constructor, you can create a generic function which dynamically performs the process at `javascript` at Answer, then returns the instance.

Comment: Yup, you're right; thanks for pointing that out. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Note, the process at `javascript` at Answer returns all of the parameters passed; see spread element at `constructor` of the extended `class`. Why did you not include the actual requirement at original Question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130555/discussion-between-neezer-and-guest271314).

Comment: Requirement for use with multiple constructors in this follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130848/generic-reading-of-arguments-from-multiple-constructor-calls