# Generic reading of arguments from multiple constructor calls

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, arguments

Follow-up question to [Read arguments from constructor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129031/read-arguments-from-constructor-call/):

The accepted solution allows me to get arguments passed into a constructor by defining a wrapper class that captures and exposes the arguments, but this leaves me with the problem of having `n` wrappers for `n` constructors.

Is there a way to have 1 function/wrapper/whatever that could work for any number of constructors?

I'll reiterate that I'm pursing this technique specifically to test [Webpack plugin configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/), and I'd like to avoid having a separate wrapper for each plugin that I need to test.

Looking for something along the lines of

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------ a wrapper function?

const someWrapper = () => { /* ... */ }

const plugin1 = new Plugin({ a: 'value' })
const plugin2 = new Plugin2(arg1, arg2, { b: 'anotherValue '})

someWrapper(plugin1).args === [{ a: 'value' }]
someWrapper(plugin2).args === [arg1, arg2, { b: 'anotherValue' }]

// --------------------------------------------------------------- a wrapper class?

class Wrapper { /* ... */ }

const plugin1 = new Wrapper(Plugin, [{ a: 'value' }])
const plugin2 = new Wrapper(Plugin2, [arg1, arg2, { b: 'anotherValue '}])

plugin1.args === [{ a: 'value' }]
plugin2.args === [arg1, arg2, { b: 'anotherValue '}]

// problem with above is the wrapper is being passed to Webpack, not the underlying
// plugin; not sure yet if this would cause webpack to break or not actually
// execute the plugin as intended with a vanilla config

// ---------------------------------------------------------------- something else?
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create generic wrapper which will add `args` property to instance of any passed constructor:

```js
class Plugin {
  constructor (arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1
    this.arg2 = arg2    
  }
}

function wrapper(initial) {
  // Rewrite initial constructor with our function
  return function decoratedContructor(...args) {
    // Create instance of initial object
    const decorated = new initial(...args)

    // Add some additional properties, methods
    decorated.args = [...args]

    // Return instantiated and modified object
    return decorated
  }
}

const decoratedPlugin = wrapper(Plugin)
const plugin = new decoratedPlugin('argument', { 'argument2': 1 })
console.log(plugin.args)
```

FYI: it's not safe to add properties without some prefix. Consider adding `__` or something like this to your property, because you can accidentally rewrite some inner object property.

Comment: _"FYI: it's not safe to add properties without some prefix"_ Good point.

Comment: I'm trying this with an actual Webpack plugin and it fails with `TypeError: decoratedPlugin is not a constructor`. Think I faithfully reproduced your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working with a modification to @guest271314's suggestion, namely, you need to pass `...initArgs` to `super()`, otherwise webpack will fail with a `TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined`.

Also took @terales's point into account about making sure to prefix my additional properties.

```
const exposeConstructorArgs = (Plugin, ...args) => {
  const ExposedPlugin = class extends Plugin {
    constructor(...initArgs) {
      super(...initArgs);

      this.__initArgs__ = initArgs;
    }

    get __initArgs() {
      return this.__initArgs__;
    }
  };

  return Reflect.construct(ExposedPlugin, args);
};

// ...

const dllPlugin = exposeConstructorArgs(webpack.DllPlugin, {
  name: '[name]',
  path: path.join(buildDir, '[name].json'),
});

// ...

const pluginConfig = dllPlugin.__initArgs[0];

expect(pluginConfig.name).toEqual('[name]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic function where [`class expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) is used within function body. Pass reference to the `class` or `constructor` and parameters expected to be `arguments` within the instance to the function call.

```js
function Plugin() {}

function Plugin2() {}

function PluginWrapper(pluginRef, ...args) {
  let MyPlugin = class extends pluginRef {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.args = [...arguments];
    }
    getArgs() {
      return this.args;
    }
  }
  return Reflect.construct(MyPlugin, args);
};

const anInstance = PluginWrapper(Plugin, {
  a: 'path'
});

console.log(anInstance.getArgs(), anInstance instanceof Plugin);

const aSecondInstance = PluginWrapper(Plugin2, "arg1", "arg2", {
  b: 'anotherPath'
});

console.log(aSecondInstance.getArgs(), aSecondInstance instanceof Plugin2);
```